# Converage rate of product

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

There are two vectors $\mathbf{a}$ and $\mathbf{b}$ of length $M$ where their entries follow the normal distribution, i.e., $a_i \sim \mathcal{N}(0, \alpha)$ and $b_i \sim \mathcal{N}(0, \beta)$. With the assumption $\alpha \neq \beta$, we have:

$$\mathbf{a}^T \mathbf{b} \rightarrow 0 \mbox{ when } M \rightarrow \infty$$

One textbook says that the convergence rate of $\mathbf{a}^T \mathbf{b}  \rightarrow 0 $ is $\sqrt{M}$ but I do not know why they can come up with this rate. Do you have any idea?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't see in what sense this sum converges to zero... Maybe you should explain this better..

Comment: Yeah, please do not leave out so many details when posting questions here. For example, I guess the $a_i$'s form an independent sequence (similarly for $b_i$'s) and also that the sequence $(a_i)_i$ is independent of $(b_i)_i$. Also, in what sense do you want to show this convergence? As a hint: $\sqrt{M}$ rates are provided by the Central Limit Theorem...